# Java GUI Programming Only Restarts once

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I have a program here that changes an avatars hat and earrings
the problem is that it only restarts once (the load button only works once)

This is what I have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Lab14_Navarro extends JFrame {
private int x,y,z;
private Container game;
private JComboBox Head;
private JComboBox Ear;
private JLabel Avatar;
private JTextArea details;
private String []Hat = {"No Hat", "Captain Hat", "Black Leather Hat"};
private JButton load;
private String []Earrings = {"No Earrings", "Silver Dangling Earrings", "Gold Dangling   Earrings"};
private ImageIcon [] Accessories =
{ new ImageIcon("blackleather.PNG"),//0
  new ImageIcon("blackleather_goldear.PNG"),//1
  new ImageIcon("blackleather_silverear.PNG"),//2
  new ImageIcon("captainhat.PNG"),//3
  new ImageIcon("captainhat_goldear.PNG"),//4
  new ImageIcon("captainhat_silverear.PNG"),//5
  new ImageIcon("goldear.PNG"),//6
  new ImageIcon("noaccessories.PNG"),//7
  new ImageIcon("silverear.PNG")};//8

/**
 * Creates a new instance of <code>Lab14_Navarro</code>.
 */
public Lab14_Navarro() {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
    setTitle("Avatar!");
    setSize(250,450);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game = getContentPane();
    game.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Head = new JComboBox(Hat);
    Ear = new JComboBox(Earrings);
    Avatar = new JLabel(Accessories[7]);
    load = new JButton("Load Image");
    details = new JTextArea("AVATAR DETAILS:               "+"\n"+"     Hat:            "+Hat[Head.getSelectedIndex()]+"\n"+"     Earrings:   "+Earrings[Ear.getSelectedIndex()]);
    game.add(Avatar);
    game.add(Head);
    game.add(Ear);
    game.add(load);
    game.add(details, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
    details.setEditable(false);
    Head.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JComboBox temphead = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            int temphat = (int) temphead.getSelectedIndex();
            x = temphat;
        }
    });
    Ear.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            JComboBox tempear = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            int tempearrings = (int) tempear.getSelectedIndex();
            y = tempearrings;
        }
    });
    load.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        if(x==0&&y==0){
            z = 7;
        }
        if(x==0&&y==1){
            z = 8;
        }
        if(x==0&&y==2){
            z = 6;
        }
        if(x==1&&y==0){
            z = 3;
        }
        if(x==1&&y==1){
            z = 5;
        }
        if(x==1&&y==2){
            z = 4;
        }
        if(x==2&&y==0){
            z = 0;
        }
        if(x==2&&y==1){
            z = 2;
        }
        if(x==2&&y==2){
            z = 1;
        }

        setTitle("Avatar");
        setSize(250,450);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game = getContentPane();
        game.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Head = new JComboBox(Hat);
        Ear = new JComboBox(Earrings);
        Avatar = new JLabel(Accessories[z]);
        load = new JButton("Load Image");
        details = new JTextArea("AVATAR DETAILS:               "+"\n"+"     Hat:            "+Hat[x]+"\n"+"     Earrings:   "+Earrings[y]);
        game.add(Avatar);
        game.add(Head);
        game.add(Ear);
        game.add(load);
        game.add(details, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        details.setEditable(false);

        }
        });



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lab14_Navarro fs = new Lab14_Navarro();
    fs.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}
Any help is accepted thanks
I just started Java so I'm not that good... yet

Answer (score 3):

When you write, for the second time:

```
load = new JButton("Load Image");
```

you're creating a new button, however, you are not giving it a new ActionListener

On another note, you don't need to create a new Button, your original load button is still there, you need only to add it to the contentPane again.